# Subgradient descent: compute subgradient(s) in the point where the objective is nondifferentiable

Tags: logistic, regularization, gradient-descent, gradient

The task of subgradient descent naturally appears in cases of L1 regularization:

$$f(\vec{\theta}) = loss + \lambda\sum{|\theta|}$$

Here we use subderivatives to update current location in a parameter space during iterative optimization procedure. The question is what is the algorithm behavior when some of the $\theta$ is 0. In that case subderivative is not a singleton set (which is basically a derivative of the function) but instead an interval:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_i}f(\vec{\theta}) =  \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_i}loss + a, a \in [-\lambda, \lambda], \theta_i = 0$$

In this particular case (of L1 regularization) we choose a single value from a subgradient interval - 0, so that regularization component doesn't update parameters.
But in general, in subgradient descent algorithm objective function is unknown we just have it's subgradient. How do we choose a particular one in such points where the objective is not differentiable?

Comment: have you solved this problem?